# Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Bookingday>?' in type cast with Flutter Hive

Tags: flutter, dart, local-storage, flutter-hive

Following problem:

I have Hive in my project and there I save Lists of Objects. When I store something while I use the app, and want to get the data from Hive (still same session), then everything is fine and I got the data which I previously stored in Hive. When I look in my document Folder, there is also a .Hive file, where my data is stored. But after I close the app, and when I want to get the data from Hive, then it tells me:

```
" type 'Unhandled exception:
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Bookingday>?' in type cast
#0      BoxImpl.get (package:hive/src/box/box_impl.dart:44:26)
#1      BookingDAO.Eval ()
#2      BookingDAO.getStoredWeek (package:workplace/utils/booking_dao.dart:23:36)
#3      _ReservationsState.initState (package:workplace/pages/reservations.dart:44:30)
```

I can't understand such behaviour. Why does it works well, when I store and get the data in the same session, but after restarting the app, it says the List is of type dynamic?
Can it have something to do with how I open and close Hive?

My method:

```
    Box<List<Bookingday>> boxList = Hive.box<List<Bookingday>>(bookingDayBoxName);

    List<Bookingday> getStoredWeek(DateTime firstJan, DateTime date) {
        String key = getCalenderWeek(firstJan, date);
        try {
          List<Bookingday>? bookList = boxList.get(key);
          if (bookList != null) {
            bookingdays = bookList;
            return bookList;
          } else {
            return List.generate(
                getWeek(dateNow).length,
                (index) => Bookingday(
                    day: dateNow,
                    parkingSlotReserved: false,
                    capacityCounter: 0,
                    maxCapacity: 4));
          }
        } catch (e) {
            if (e is TypeError) {}
        }
        return bookingdays;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Box<List> box = Hive.box<List>(bookingDayBoxName);
var list = box.get(key, defaultValue: [])?.cast<Bookingday>();
```

[because a limitation of Dart](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/138#issuecomment-559722635)

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast

```
Box<List<Bookingday>> boxList = Hive.box<List<Bookingday>>(bookingDayBoxName);

    List<Bookingday> getStoredWeek(DateTime firstJan, DateTime date) {
        String key = getCalenderWeek(firstJan, date);
        try {
          List<Bookingday>? bookList = boxList.get(key);
          if (bookList != null) {
            bookingdays = bookList!;
            return bookList;
          } else {
            return List.generate(
                getWeek(dateNow).length,
                (index) => Bookingday(
                    day: dateNow,
                    parkingSlotReserved: false,
                    capacityCounter: 0,
                    maxCapacity: 4)).cast<Bookingday>();
          }
        } catch (e) {
            if (e is TypeError) {}
        }
        return bookingdays;
     }
```

Comment: There is no problem with the else statement. The exception occurs in the "boxList.get(key)" Line.